# setCustomValidity() working only on first row of dynamic table lightning

Tags: lightning, lightninginput

I have a requirement where I need to dynamically add/remove table rows and add custom validation on each row in LWC.

I achieved dynamically adding and deleting rows but while adding setCustomValidity() and reportValidity(), the custom error message is thrown only at the first row everytime.

How to make the custom message appear for each dynamic row added.

Below is the screenshot where the validation for second row is appearing at first row:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<template for:each={listOfAccounts} for:item="rec">
                        <tr key={rec} class="slds-hint-parent">
                           
        
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input type="text" class="validate1" required="true" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
        
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input type="email" class="validate2" required="true" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Website" value={rec.Website} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <template if:true={visibledelete}>
                                <td>
                                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Remove" title="Remove" name={rec.index} onclick={removeRow}></lightning-button-icon>
                                </td>
                            </template>
                          
                        </tr>
                    </template>
```

Written the validations in `handleInputChange()`;

```
handleInputChange(event) {
        let index = event.target.dataset.id;
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;
        let emailRegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; 
        console.log('index:::'+index);

                 //Input field validations start
                 if(fieldName == 'Name'){
                    let inputFields1 = event.target.value;
                    let inputFieldsName = this.template.querySelector('.validate1');
                    if(inputFields1 == ""){
                        inputFieldsName.setCustomValidity("This field is required");
                        inputFieldsName.reportValidity();
                        this.isValid1 = false;
                    }else{
                        inputFieldsName.setCustomValidity("");
                        this.isValid1 = true;
                    }
                    }else if(fieldName == 'Website'){
                        let inputFields2 = event.target.value;
                        let inputFieldsEmail = this.template.querySelector('.validate2');
                        if(inputFields2 == ""){
                            inputFieldsEmail.setCustomValidity("This field is required");
                            inputFieldsEmail.reportValidity();
                            this.isValid1 = false;
                        }else if(!inputFields2.match(emailRegExp)){
                            inputFieldsEmail.setCustomValidity("Sorry that's an invalid email address.Please check and try again");
                            inputFieldsEmail.reportValidity();
                            this.isValid1 = false;
                        }else{
                            inputFieldsEmail.setCustomValidity("");
                            this.isValid1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                    //Input field validations end

        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfAccounts.length; i++) {
            if(this.listOfAccounts[i].index === parseInt(index)) {
                this.listOfAccounts[i][fieldName] = value;       
            }
        }
    }
```

How to make the custom validation message appear for each newly added row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let inputFieldsName = this.template.querySelector('.validate1');
```

You're querying the first row's input element, as querySelector stops after the first element found. Instead:

```
let inputFieldsName = event.target;
```

This is the element that is actually being handled right now.

Comment: can you elaborate please. Since I want a different validation message for both input fields, I tried to identify the lightning-inputs with query selector. Can you give me a brief snippet of your suggestion.

Comment: @SafalaKolaventi `event.target` holds the `lightning-input` field that triggered the event. You do not need to query the DOM to find that field, as you already have it available in the `event` object.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did manage to align the error messages as required by above approach, however just want to know how to trigger the same validations on clicking Save button.

I have written a method to fire validations on submit button but it does nothing:



validateFields() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {
            element.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
            element.reportValidity();
        });
    }

Comment: @SafalaKolaventi `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a normal Array object, so you have to convert it first: `[...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')].forEach(...` Where `[...arrayLike]` copies the elements of an array-like (has length and indexed properties) into a proper array. This is the Spread Operator, which you can read more about on MDN.